# C# - How to set a ComboBox selectedItem from specific value?

Tags: c#, combobox

I have this already populated ComboBox and all I want to do is to set it to a specific selectedItem knowing its value.

I'm trying this, but nothing happens:

```
comboPublisher.SelectedValue = livre.Editeur;
```

Considering the fact that I already implemented Equals(..) method in my class Editeur, this way:

```
  public  bool Equals(IEditeur editeur)
        {
            return (this.Nom == editeur.Nom);
        }
```

This is how I populate my ComboBox:

```
foreach (Business.IEditeur editeur in _livreManager.GetPublishers())
        {
            comboPublisher.Items.Add(editeur);
        }
```

Any idea ?

Thanks !

[EDIT]: This seems to work with :

```
comboPublisher.SelectedItem = livre.Editeur;
```

My Equals method is:

```
 public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            IEditeur editeur = new Editeur();

            if (!(obj is System.DBNull))
            {
                editeur = (IEditeur)obj;
                return (this.Nom == editeur.Nom);
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Note, SelectedValue only works if you have specified the ValueMember. Therefore, SelectedItem is the next choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `DataSources` in case of WinForm / `ItemsSource` in case of WPF to your cobobox then you can use SelectedValue properly.

***[Update]***
Instead of add each item to your combobox directly, you should create collection to hold those items and then set it as your DataSource (WinForm) / ItemsSource (WPF)

```
foreach (Business.IEditeur editeur in _livreManager.GetPublishers())
{
    //comboPublisher.Items.Add(editeur);
    list.Add(editeur);
}

combobox.ItemsSource = editeur;
combobox.SelectedValuePath = "value_property_name";
combobox.DisplayMemberPath = "display_property_name";
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the Text property.

Comment: I believe it works all the time, because you are setting programmatically. (I would have to verify.)

Answer (score 2):

you've created a new implementation of Equals that hides the one in Object.  Try declaring it with `public override bool` and see if that helps.

Comment: You're right I forgot override. It still doesn't solve the problem though :(

Comment: I always use SelectedItem... maybe that's why.  :)

Answer (score 0):

In think that you have also to implement IEquatable in Editeur class, but passing an object as argument. Something like this. The rest of your code is fine.

```
public bool Equals(Editeur other)
{
    return (this.Nom == other.Nom);            
}

public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    if (obj is Editeur)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Editeur);
    }
    return false;
}
```