# Set the selecteditem of a combobox based on key,value pair.

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I have a combobox that I populate like this:

```
this.reqTypeInput.Items.Add(new RequestType("Label 1", "Value1"));
this.reqTypeInput.Items.Add(new RequestType("Label 2", "value2"));
this.reqTypeInput.Items.Add(new RequestType("Label 3", "value3"));
```

My RequestType class is:

```
class RequestType
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public RequestType(string text, string val)
    {
        Text = text;
        Value = val;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Text;
    }
}
```

I have a value, "Value1" for example. How can I set the selectedItem of the combobox to the object {Label 1, Value1}?

I have tried:

```
this.reqTypeInput.SelectedIndex = this.reqTypeInput.Items.IndexOf("Value1");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the request types do not change, you could store each RequestType object in a variable first, then set the [SelectedItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem.aspx) property of the ComboBox to that variable.

For example:

```
RequestType type1 = New RequestType("Label 1", "Value 1");
RequestType type2 = New RequestType("Label 2", "Value 2");

reqTypeInput.Items.Add(type1);
reqTypeInput.Items.Add(type2);
```

Then, set it like this:

```
reqTypeInput.SelectedItem = type2;
```

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are trying to find the index as though your `ComboBox` contains just string values, when it actually contains `RequestType` objects. Have you tried overriding your `Equals` operator?

Check out [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2384009/c-sharp-how-to-set-a-combobox-selecteditem-from-specific-value), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447637/wpf-combobox-selecteditem-hell) for examples of overriding `Equals`.

**EDIT**: As mentioned in another answer, a good practice is to populate a collection of objects that you want in the `ComboBox`, then bind that collection to your `ComboBox`. The first link in my answer here has an example of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
RequestType type1 = New RequestType("Label 1", "Value 1");
RequestType type2 = New RequestType("Label 2", "Value 2");

reqTypeInput.Items.Add(type1);
reqTypeInput.Items.Add(type2);

this.reqTypeInput.SelectedIndex = this.reqTypeInput.Items.IndexOf(type1);
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

Lot's of choices, List, SortedList, Dictionary, SortedDictionary.
But basicall you keep your collection of RequestTypes in a list and then populate the combo from it, you could even bind if you wish.

The only thing the combo knopws about your collection of request types, is the result of each RequestType's ToString method. If you want find by Value, then Combox will only see waht you put in it, which was RequestType.ToString()